# spring-integration-aws based on AWS SDK for Java 2.x for SQS based spring batch remote partitioning

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, spring-integration-aws

Do we have a version spring-integration-aws version available that uses AWS SDK 2.x for creating SNS-SQS adaptors.My use case requires me to use spring-integration-aws as I am doing a spring batch remote partitioning via SQS but want to use latest AWS SDK underneath as am facing some issues with V1.Also all other use cases of my app needs V2.Could somebody provide some pointers?

Comment: You can use AWS SDK for Java V2 and invoke Amazon SQS and use the functionity in a Spring based app. Its also best practice to move away from Java V1 to V2.

Comment: @smac2020 we are using spring-integration-aws base classes that is built on AWS SDK V1 and unless we have a V2 version of the spring-integration-aws base class we have to continue using V1 .The issue that am getting is it is unable to access valid SQS although listQueues etc works .Also this is from an EKS pod

Comment: See https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws 3.0.0-RC1. It has support for v2 and sqs and sns

Comment: @spencergibb I am looking for a SDK V2 replacement for the below SQS adapator that is used via spring integration                                           https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/v3.0.0-M1/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/outbound/SqsMessageHandler.java

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/155

Comment: @spencergibb thank you ..it looks like we have to wait for this .